# How to write a JUnit unit test for database call?

Tags: java, database, unit-testing, junit

For example, if I have something like this:

```
try {
 // db call
} catch ( Exception e ) {
 return false
}
```

I want to write a unit test to test this method. How should I write that? Or to say it differently, what will be an example of code that will cause SQLException or any other exception to be thrown?

Comment: I did not understand what you intend to do. If you want this to issue a SqlException simply pass an invalid command to the database

Comment: What's the behavior you want to test? Is it the database call, or some code that handles the database call? If the latter, you might consider using a mocking library (google around to find one -- I suggest Mockito) to simulate your db.

Comment: I want to test a database call. So I am assuming,  ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT FROM SubDeptTable"); will throw an error since the query is incorrect

Comment: You will be much happier IMO if you choose to use a mocking library instead of connecting to an actual database and running an invalid command. You are trying to test that if a SqlException is thrown then your method returns false, right? If that's the case, use Mockito to mock a call to your database.

Answer (score 0):

We usually write such a test code like this:

```
try {
    // Do something you expect to fail.
    Assert.fail();
} catch (SQLException e) { // Expected exception type.
    Assert.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), "Expected message");
    // Or alternatively.
    Assert.assertTrue(e.getMessage().startsWith("Expected start of the message"));
}
```

The Assert.fail() part makes sure that the test fails in case the code did not throw the error.